# How to return customized response to api /rest-auth/login/ in Django Framework

Tags: python, django

Here is sample code,Instead of returning None, I want to return some custom message ie. what exactly the error is as response object in return.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import authentication
from rest_framework import exceptions

class ExampleAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        username = request.META.get('X_USERNAME')
        if not username:
            return None

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('No such user')

        return (user, None)
```

Comment: Can you tell a little bit more what do you want to achieve and are you using some 3rd party lib? If not I would advise you against custom authentication since there are some pretty good libraries that you can override for you needs.

Comment: Hey Alphii, I am trying to authenticate username and password via this class. I am able to fetch username in this class. After validating it, I am trying to send customized response from this class back to consumer who is consuming this api  /rest-auth/login/  as CustomAuthentication class will be executed at the time of calling api /rest-auth/login/. Hope you got some idea what I am trying, If not let me know friend.

Comment: Hii Alphii, I updated the my code. Please have a look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Do some thing like this

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import authentication
from rest_framework import exceptions
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

class ExampleAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        username = request.META.get('X_USERNAME')
        if not username:
            return Response("some response", status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            return Response("user logged in successfully", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('No such user')
            return Response("No such user", status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

In this way you can send custom response.

Comment: @ Teja Thanks, Lemme try this one. I'll update here whether it is working for me or not.

Comment: Hii Teja, I updated the my code. Please have a look into that.

Comment: Hi Sunil, I have updated my answer as per you code in question. Hope it helps!